# Access won't open past the splash screen

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc, splash-screen

I am writing a front end in Access that connects to SQL Server. I am using the default {SQL Server} driver since some of the computers/laptops/tablets that will be using it probably will not have a driver installed for SQL Server. The FE opens fine on my computer as one would expect, and will open on another computer (that does not have any driver's installed), but when attempting to open the FE on 2 other machines, both get stuck at the ACCESS splash screen. I have checked Task Manager and the Microsoft Access (32-bit) background process is running. All of our machines are 64-bit. Can anyone help with this?

I've researched trying to find a different default driver for SQL Server but have come up empty handed. Installing a driver like {ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server} isn't feasible since it would entail having our outsourced IT company install it and charging us for it.

Follow up: It is the Microsoft Access splash screen that is locking up (the one that appears whenever you open Access), not a custom one. And I am not deploying the DB, simply sending it in an email for the user to copy to their computer. I am using Autoexec to run my Main function to connect to the backend server.
The VBA to connect is:

````vb
    Public curDB as ADODB.Recordset: Set curDB = New ADODB.Connection
    conString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=HL-XXX;Database=PalletQuoting;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX;Encrypt=NO"```
````

Comment: Checked local logs and windows logs?

Comment: Please describe and show code running during or after splash screen.

Comment: Shouldn't your setup program deploy the needed drivers alleviating the issue you're describing

Comment: You can start Access holding in SHIFT, then the app will start without running code. Afterwards you can open the relevant first form in design mode, and add a breakpoint in the code to check where it gets stuck. Assuming you use vba in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention where the SQL Server is located. However if the SQL instance is not on your computer.

Above being the case?
Then the application should work just fine from all computers on that same network.

Just make sure WHEN you link the table(s), make sure you using FILE DSN, and not a user/system DSN. The reason for this is then you don't require any setup on each workstation by using the standard SQL driver as you noted.

So, when you link the table, don't use system or user DSN, but make sure you linked the tables using a FILE DSN. By using a FILE DSN, then no setup is required on each workstation.

So, with above, then do the linked tables work and open just fine, or is it just the custom ADO code you have that fails?

I would suggest you ensure the linked tables work first before you start working on the VBA + ADO code you have.

Comment: I'm not using linked tables. Most of the queries are read only. When I actually need to make a change to the underlying data I use the .Open method of the ADODB recordset. I am using a DSN-less connection string. The server is located in Texas and is accessed from other facilities in other states. I didn't want to use linked tables due to Access importing all of the data when it connects.

Comment: Access does not import all rows of data when using inked table. If you have a form bound to a linked table with 1 million rows and open the form with a simple standard where clause like this: docmd.OpenForm "frmInvoice",,,"InvoiceNum = 123", then ONLY one row of data is pulled over the network - so your information and pretext is VAST wrong. So, no performance gains exist by using ADO or a simple linked table bound directly to a form  (all rows are NOT pulled to the client).  So, while you may not want to use linked tables, your reason provided for not doing so is wrong.

Comment: If you connection works on your computer, then those other computers and their location simply do not have the ability to connect to the server - thus this likely has little to do with Access.  If the connection works fine on some computers, then it should work on the others.

Comment: I agree that it should work on all computers if it works on some, but it doesn't. The Access splash screen pops up but never actually opens Access. It is opened in the background and that is it.  As for Access importing all records when it opens, I was under the impression that it did. I read that somewhere but have never actually tested it. I will take your word on it.  Are FILE DSNs saved in the front end? Will I need to create or copy them to the other machines?

Comment: A file dsn is only used during the link process and then is not required or used (so you can even delete the file dsn since it's not used). This in effect means the linked tables are dsn-less automatically for you and thus at that point the application can be copied to any workstation without any additional setup required.  So in effect the settings are only in the application and the dsn file is not used nor required anymore

Comment: Also, are you running office x32 or x64 bits? this will matter if you deploying a compiled accDE, since then the accDE must match the bit size of office it was created with. This is not the case for a accDB, but is for a accDE.

Comment: 64-bit, but it is accdb. I will try a File DSN. Thanks for your help and clarification.

Comment: Ok, so in VBA, make sure the debug->compile works ok, and no code errors exist....